# Random sort in linux - algo?

Tags: linux, sorting

How random sort works in linux?

What type of functions are used by system?

can we alter the behavior?

```
sort -R file
-R, --random-sort(sort by random hash of keys)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply hashes the input keys then sorts on that hash value.

The choice of hash function is a random one, usually based on a simple internal pseudo-random number generator but you can change the source of this randomness by using the `--random-source=FSPEC` option.

This will use `FSPEC` as the source of randomness for selecting the hash information, typically `/dev/random` or its kin.